# Bootstrap form not rendering without additional form element

Tags: html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem with a form inside of a modal using Bootstrap 3.2.2. Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="emailModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-close"></span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><span style="padding-right:10px;" class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></span>E-Mail Developer</h4>
            </div> <!-- .modal-header -->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="toEmailInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">To</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="toEmailInput" placeholder="Enter Email" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="subjectInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Subject</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subjectInput" placeholder="Enter Subject" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="messageInput" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Message</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <textarea class="no-resize form-control" id="messageInput" rows="5" placeholder="Enter Message"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div> <!-- .modal-body -->
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            </div> <!-- .modal-footer -->
        </div> <!-- .modal-content -->
    </div> <!-- .modal-dialog -->
</div> <!-- .modal -->
```

This renders this:
[image]

But, if I add an additional tag `<form role="form"></form>` ***anywhere in the page***, I get this:

[image]

Any idea of what witchcraft is going on behind the scenes here? I would expect it to look like the second picture *without additional form tags*.

**UPDATE** - After taking a look at the applied CSS from my before & after, it looks like the removal of the additional `<form>` tag also removes the applied `.form-horizontal` styling from the form itself. I'm continuing to investigate, but I have a feeling it has to do with something about the way the site is configured.

**UPDATE** - I found the issue. Without the additional `<form>` tag, there's some funkiness in the web app that is *removing* the surrounding `<form class="form-horizontal">` tag but leaving the form-groups alone. Very strange!

**UPDATE** - Well, surprise surprise. Turns out my ASP.NET Web Forms (yes, with a `<form runat="server">` tag) strips out "nested" form elements. Yes, I realize I didn't mention I was using web forms, but I was hoping it was unrelated. Turns out it's completely related!

Comment: would probably need to see some CSS

Comment: Works as expected in JSFiddle, so it's probably a CSS "problem" - [Link to fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kq17u5es/)

Comment: Hmmm... good point. This project has lots of crazy CSS that has been done by lots of other developers, there are probably several hidden "gems".

Comment: Is this browser specific to you or does it happen on every browser?  We would need to see the CSS rules for the following classes:  .control-label and .no-resize, I'll bet the problem has something to do with those classes and probably a little to do with the inline styles.

Comment: @ben.kaminski I was able to recreate across browsers.

Comment: You need to upload CSS as well..! or simply, upload your site, temp. somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out this is due to ASP.NET Web Form's innate ability to strip out nested `<form>` tags from its "master" `<form runat="server">` form used for post-backs.

To prove this, I changed my `<form class="form-horizontal">` into a simple `<div>` with the same class, and it worked fine.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad you were able to solve on your own.  According to Microsoft, ASP and .NET will be open-source soon so maybe some of these bugs will get worked out.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to recreate your problem in JSFiddle. So probably you should check your paddings and one margin of the following classes. I think you are overriding them by your CSS, so you should check it.

```
.modal-body {
   position: relative;
   padding: 15px;
   /*modified by me to reproduce your problem, check out where you are setting 
    the bottom padding to 0  (should be 15px)*/
   padding-bottom: 0; 
}

.form-group {
   /*modified by me to reproduce your problem, check out where you are setting 
    the bottom margin to 0  (should be 15px)*/
   margin-bottom: 0px;
}

.modal-footer {
   padding: 15px;
   text-align: right;
   border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
   /*modified by me to reproduce your problem, check out where you are setting 
    the bottom & right padding to 0  (should be 15px)*/
   padding-top: 0;
   padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Ramis, thanks for this. In Chrome, I'm able to see that, for the most part, those styles are being applied. What's weird is that `.form-horizontal` is removed when I remove the arbitrary `<form>` element.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my fiddle using your code:

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tzhben/r1jtef9y/3/)

I added a button for ease of use.  Because i'm not referencing the stylesheet that has the "**.control-label**" and "**.no-resize**" classes, I'm not getting the same problem.

I really think that your issue lies in one of those two aforementioned classes that are not BootStrap classes.

Can you share the rules for those two classes?

Thanks!

```
.control-label {?}
.no-resize {?}
```